Multiple JOINs is extremely slow on SQLite
I'm using EF Core with SQLite. For the MCVE, let's say, I only have these tables [DomesticContainers, DomesticRecords, InternationalContainers, InternationalRecords, Clients], where there's a one-to-many relationship between the XXXXContainers and XXXXRecords tables and a one-to-many relationship between the XXXXContainers and Clients tables.
Table definitions:
CREATE TABLE "DomesticContainers" (
    "Id"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "Name"  TEXT,
    CONSTRAINT "PK_DomesticContainers" PRIMARY KEY("Id" AUTOINCREMENT)
);

CREATE TABLE "DomesticRecords" (
    "Id"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "Zone"  TEXT,
    "ContainerId"   INTEGER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "PK_DomesticRecords" PRIMARY KEY("Id" AUTOINCREMENT),
    CONSTRAINT "FK_DomesticRecords_DomesticContainers_ContainerId" FOREIGN KEY("ContainerId") REFERENCES "DomesticContainers"("Id") ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE "InternationalContainers" (
    "Id"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "Name"  TEXT,
    CONSTRAINT "PK_InternationalContainers" PRIMARY KEY("Id" AUTOINCREMENT)
);

CREATE TABLE "InternationalRecords" (
    "Id"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "CountryCode"   TEXT,
    "ContainerId"   INTEGER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "PK_InternationalRecords" PRIMARY KEY("Id" AUTOINCREMENT),
    CONSTRAINT "FK_InternationalRecords_InternationalContainers_ContainerId" FOREIGN KEY("ContainerId") REFERENCES "InternationalContainers"("Id") ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE "Clients" (
    "Id"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "Name"  TEXT,
    "DomesticContainerId"   INTEGER,
    "InternationalContainerId"  INTEGER,
    CONSTRAINT "PK_Clients" PRIMARY KEY("Id" AUTOINCREMENT),
    CONSTRAINT "FK_Clients_InternationalContainers_InternationalContainerId" FOREIGN KEY("InternationalContainerId") REFERENCES "InternationalContainers"("Id"),
    CONSTRAINT "FK_Clients_DomesticContainers_DomesticContainerId" FOREIGN KEY("DomesticContainerId") REFERENCES "DomesticContainers"("Id")
);

Now, I was trying to use multiple Include with ThenInclude in EF Core. Something like this:
var query = context.Clients
   .Include((c) => c.InternationalContainer).ThenInclude((ic) => ic.LinkedRecords)
   .Include((c) => c.DomesticContainer).ThenInclude((dc) => dc.LinkedRecords);

But that was extremely slow, so I decided to try and run the generated SQL query myself:
SELECT "c"."Id", "c"."Name", "d"."Id", "d"."Name", "i"."Id", "d0"."Id", "d0"."ContainerId", "d0"."Zone", "i"."Name", "i0"."Id", "i0"."ContainerId", "i0"."CountryCode"
FROM "Clients" AS "c"
LEFT JOIN "DomesticContainers" AS "d" ON "c"."DomesticContainerId" = "d"."Id"
LEFT JOIN "InternationalContainers" AS "i" ON "c"."InternationalContainerId" = "i"."Id"
LEFT JOIN "DomesticRecords" AS "d0" ON "d"."Id" = "d0"."ContainerId"
LEFT JOIN "InternationalRecords" AS "i0" ON "i"."Id" = "i0"."ContainerId"
ORDER BY "c"."Id", "d"."Id", "i"."Id", "d0"."Id"

And again, it was extremely slow that practically it never finishes.
If I try to use one Include-ThenInclude pair (i.e., two JOINs instead of four), the query finishes almost instantly. So, it can separately retrieve all domestic records associated with a client or all international records associated with a client, but when I try to get both at the same time, it haults.
What am I doing wrong?
I have <4k records in DomesticRecords, <65k in 'InternationalRecords', and I ran this test with a single record in all of the Clients, DomesticContainers, and InternationalContainers tables.

The usual suspect: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/single-split-queries. You can probably find duplicate questions.

@GertArnold AsSplitQuery() did the trick. Thanks a lot!!!
